# what activity elevates your center of gravity?

Tags: workout-routines, workout, upper-body-workout, sports

what sport or workout would elevate your center of mass/gravity?
 bigger arms, tighter calves. would sprinting be a good exercise for this?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive on what "raising your centre of gravity" means? Beyond gaining muscle mass in your upper body and not your lower I'm unsure how else you expect to move your centre of mass upwards.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to move your center of gravity upwards? As a rather tall guy, I can't think of a situation where having a lower center of gravity would be a bad thing

Comment: @DarkHippo as a short guy who judoed, now trying to get good at basketball, i find having a lower center of gravity harder to sprint and jump. But yes, I do know in combat/wrestling sport this is an advantage.

Comment: Ah, fair point, that's not something I'd considered. My point of view does mainly come from combat sports as well as rollerskating and attempts at surfing :)

Comment: @user2167582 - What makes you think a lower center of gravity is a limiting factor in sprinting and jumping?

Comment: @JohnP that's just my knowledge of how sprinting and jumping works, which is pretty much survival of the sickest, you gain the ability to run b/c your body is essentially more free fall.

Comment: @user2167582 so...short gymnasts shouldn't be able to jump so high, no? :) jumping is as much about technique as strength. I will post an answer when i am not on mobile.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because raising or lowering a person's center of gravity is not directly related to physical fitness.

Comment: @EricKaufman maybe not to you, but it is a concern for people who understand the advantage when training for track / track related sports.

Comment: @EricKaufman which stack exchange do you think this question belongs to?